# Azure Synapse - How to read data from Azure Cosmos DB container containing multiple types in same collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I have a container in Azure Cosmos DB that has multiple document types in the same container. So based on the type, the key pairs change. I'm trying to read the data from this container in Synapse using the following code:

```py
cfg = {
"spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": Endpoint,
"spark.cosmos.accountKey": accountKey,
"spark.cosmos.database": databaseName,
"spark.cosmos.container": containerName,
}

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg)\
    .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled","true").load()
```

However, the schema that I'm getting through this dataframe is of the first row's type. How can I ensure that I read data for one particular type and the schema is inferred accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple document types in one container, use the `spark.cosmos.read.customQuery` parameter in the configuration to get a particular document type as a spark dataframe:

```py
cfg = {
"spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": Endpoint,
"spark.cosmos.accountKey": accountKey,
"spark.cosmos.database": databaseName,
"spark.cosmos.container": containerName,
"spark.cosmos.read.customQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.typ = TYPE_NAME"
}

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg)\
    .option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled","true").load()
```

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the customQuery config option above (that would actually hard-code the query sent to Cosmos backend vs. relying on filter push-down in Spark) you can also use the config option "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.query" - this will just change the query used for schema inferrence - but otherwise rely on filter pushdown (which can result in better query performance in some cases)

```
cfg = {
"spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": Endpoint,
"spark.cosmos.accountKey": accountKey,
"spark.cosmos.database": databaseName,
"spark.cosmos.container": containerName,
"spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.query": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.typ = TYPE_NAME"
}
```